# Code Coverage Tools & Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, testing

Just wondering what people are using for code coverage tools when using MS Visual Studio 2008 Pro.  We are using the built-in MS test project and unit testing tool (the one that come pre-installed with MS VS 2008 pro)!

Comment: Good question. I used to use this tool pretty extensively when we were running team system. However, our dev team got downgraded to the pro-edition because of the cost and I've been looking for a good inexpensive option to get code coverage functionality back.

Answer (score 5):

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) is a very popular choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you go with NUnit for tests and NCover for coverage.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the built-in testing tool in VS, especially if they already have a suite of tests using it...

Comment: VS coverage only supports statement level as for my experience. If you are looking for decision level coverage you'll need to look for better tools.

Comment: I have also found the VS functionality to be the usual UI mess, and difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) addin you will get a very good unit test runner and NCover thrown in as well. Get the personal developer version. This is realy the best ever addin for visual studio.